# R - How to add reporting level from 2 columns of emp and supervisor

Tags: r

This is related to employer to supervisor levels  provided in col 1 and 2. how to add columns to arrive at next levels?

```
Emp = c("k","j","b","s","sy","an","d","a")
Sup = c("d","k","j","k","an","a","a","")
RR <- data.frame(Emp,Sup)
nams <- c("Emp","Sup","Sup1","Sup2","Sup3")
RR[,3:5] <- NA
colnames(RR) <- nams
for(j in 1:3){
  for(i in 1:8){
    do<- RR[i,(j+1)]
    for (k in 1:8){
      if(is.na(do)) {do=FALSE} else {if(do == RR[k,1]){
        RR[i,(j+2)] <- RR[k,2]
      }
      }
    }
  }
}
RR
```

output is

```
  Emp Sup Sup1 Sup2 Sup3
1   k   d    a      <NA>
2   j   k    d    a     
3   b   j    k    d    a
4   s   k    d    a     
5  sy  an    a      <NA>
6  an   a      <NA> <NA>
7   d   a      <NA> <NA>
8   a     <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Here the reporting is seen.  Is there a simpler code? as a novice need help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
#create a similar dataframe before start of loop
RRn <- RR

#loop
for(i in 1:nrow(RR)){
  RRn <- merge(RRn, RR, by.x = ncol(RRn), by.y = 1, all.x = T, all.y = F, suffixes = c("", as.character(i+1)))
  if(sum(is.na(RRn[ncol(RRn)])) == nrow(RRn)){
    RRn[ncol(RRn)] <- NULL
    RRn <- RRn[order(colnames(RRn))]
    break
  }
}

> RRn
  Emp  Sup Sup2 Sup3 Sup4
1   b    j    k    d    a
2   j    k    d    a <NA>
3   s    k    d    a <NA>
4  sy   an    a <NA> <NA>
5   k    d    a <NA> <NA>
6  an    a <NA> <NA> <NA>
7   d    a <NA> <NA> <NA>
8   a <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

**Note** If you have more than 10 levels of reporting you can format accordingly in suffixes argument.

*This will merge `RR` with `newRR` (named RRn) until the last row becomes all NA and hence the break statement*

*obviously this loop will have to carry out max of (number of) row times*

Data used

```
Emp = c("k","j","b","s","sy","an","d","a")
Sup = c("d","k","j","k","an","a","a", NA_character_)
RR <- data.frame(Emp,Sup)
```

Comment: Thank you @anilgoyal  , simple code. i may had to add few lines to sort it as per the original sequence and have the correct colnames. Is they a way to not disturb the original sequence of the 1st 2 columns?

Comment: Thanks for accepting.  See revised code/answer for order of columns in output